# Unable to access value from PHP Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I was trying a shipment API. The API returns object. But when I try to access a certain value using a simple `foreach` loop, it does not work as intended. I tried different methods but everything gives me a blank page.

Following is the response received from the API.

```
stdClass Object
(
[ConsignmentTrackEvents_Details_NewResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ConsignmentTrack] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ERROR] => 
                        [DOCKNO] => 888888
                        [TRANSIT_LOCATION] => Location, Location
                        [ACTIVITY] => Out For Delivery
                        [EVENTDATE] => 22 Jul 2016
                        [EVENTTIME] => 21:05:48
                        [NEXT_LOCATION] => Coimbatore
                        [TRACKING_CODE] => O
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ERROR] => 
                        [DOCKNO] => 888888
                        [TRANSIT_LOCATION] => Location, Location
                        [ACTIVITY] => Picked up and Booking processed 
                        [EVENTDATE] => 06 Jun 2016
                        [EVENTTIME] => 16:40:39
                        [NEXT_LOCATION] => 
                        [TRACKING_CODE] => B
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Then I used the following loop to access the values.

```
foreach($result['ConsignmentTrackEvents_Details_NewResult'] ['ConsignmentTrack'] as $res){

echo $res['DOCKNO'];

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: That's an *object* not an *array*. Use object notation, not array notation.

Comment: Change the following `foreach($result->ConsignmentTrackEvents_Details_NewResult->ConsignmentTrack as $res)` and `echo $res->DOCKNO;`

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, now I understand it.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array and Object are different things, you access array entry with `$array['key']` and object property with `$object->key`

```
foreach($result->ConsignmentTrackEvents_Details_NewResult->ConsignmentTrack as $res){
    echo $res->DOCKNO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ianis for the help and the clarification. I have been learning PHP as part of a project and only learned up to Arrays so far and this code confused me with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could Loop through the Main Collection with a `foreach` Loop and then drill down to object contained within it, which (in turn) contains the data you are looking for.

```
<?php
   // $result HERE IS THE MAIN DATA...
    foreach($result as $key=>$data){
        $trackResult    = $result['ConsignmentTrackEvents_Details_NewResult'];
        foreach($trackResult as $intKey=>$objData){
            $dockNo         = $objData->DOCKNO;
            $transit        = $objData->TRANSIT_LOCATION;
            $activity       = $objData->ACTIVITY;
            $eventDate      = $objData->EVENTDATE;
            $eventTime      = $objData->EVENTTIME;
            $nextLocation   = $objData->NEXT_LOCATION;
            $trackingCode   = $objData->TRACKING_CODE;

            echo $dockNo;

        }

    }
```